# How to correctly load dependent JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, google-maps, registerclientscriptblock

I am trying to extent a website page that displays google maps with the [LabeledMarker](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/labeledmarker/1.4/). Google Maps API defines a class called GMarker which is extended by the LabeledMarker.

The problem is, I cant seem to load the LabeledMarker script properly, i.e. after the Google API loads and I get the 'GMarker not defined' error.

**What is the correct way to specify the scripts in such cases?**

I am using ASP.NET's ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude() first for the google API url and then immediately after with the LabeledMarker script file.

The initial google API loader writes further script links that load the actual GMarker class. Shouldnt all those scripts be executed before the next script block(LabeledMarker script) is processed.

I have checked the generated HTML and the script blocks are emitted in the right order.

```
<script src="google api url" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
(the above scripts uses document.write() etc to append further script blocks/sources)
...
<script src="Scripts/LabeledMarker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once again, **the LabeledMarker.js seems to get executed before the google API finishes loading.**

Comment: I do the same thing and never had this problem. Currently I include the Google jsapi script (www.google.com/jsapi?key=...), then right after, use it to load the maps api `google.load("maps", '2.132');`  then load my customization script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is the problem. I was calling google.load() in the body.onload which happened after loading the scripts. Resolved by emitting script tag for the LabeledMarker from within the onload handler.